# How to construct eigen matrix of size 1000* 1000

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am trying to construct a matrix of size `1000*1000` in Eigen library. I tried their documentation but I am still confused. I have very basic knowledge of CPP.

I tried the following. I know its not right but it would be nice if someone complete the code below

```
  int size = 1000;
  MatrixXd a(size);
  MatrixXd b(size);

  for (int i = 2; i < size; i++ ){
            a(i) = (rand()%10+1) +  ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
            b(i) = (rand()%10+1) +  ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
  }
```

Comment: This looks wrong `a(i)` - Perhaps you mean `a[i]`

Answer (score 2):

A static matrix with 1000 rows and 1000 columns:
`Eigen::Matrix<double, 1000, 1000> theMatrix;`

MatrixXd is a dynamic variant, one can change the number of rows and/or columns at runtime. For a dynamic matrix use:

`Eigen::MatrixXd theMatrix(1000,1000);`

Comment: I need dynamic one.

Comment: By the way, I don't know how urgent is this for you, but sometime this week I intend to commit on GitHub some code that relies quite heavily on Eigen. It could be useful for seeing Eigen at work even if you don't care about the numerical renormalization group. The code will be here: https://github.com/aromanro/nrg